# Strange behavior on home internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, internet

We recently had a new modem sent to us from our ISP (Armstrong). We hooked it up and tested it out and bam! We had double, almost triple the internet speed we had previously. As you could imagine, I was quite excited.

We've had the new modem for roughly a month or two now, and up until these past two weeks, it has worked flawlessly. But nothing perfect lasts forever. A favorite website of mine ([hooktheory.com](http://www.hooktheory.com)), and one frequently visited has all of sudden become unavailable. The website isn't down. I can get to it from my phone on mobile data and several other devices not connected to our home network. When going to the website, it attempts to load for roughly 30 seconds and then errors out with following information:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> hooktheory.com took too long to respond.
>
> Search Google for hooktheory
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I've attempted this from all our home devices connected to both the wifi and ethernet cable. I've tried this on all web browsers as well. I checked the DNS settings just to make sure anything wonky wasn't happening and everything looks normal.

This however, isn't the only issue I've encountered.

Today I was browsing Tumblr and I noticed none of the videos would load. It was just a black screen and eventually would show the missing image icon. I read around and tried some common troubleshooting techniques and none worked. I once again attempted this from multiple browsers and devices as well. Nothing.

I decided I'd look in to the router control panel and lo and behold, there was a firmware update. I figured that must have been it so I updated. Nope. I checked the firewall settings. Not blocking anything. I checked the logs. No info. I have no clue what to do at this point.

If anyone has any idea what might be going awry, that would be fantastic. I really need to get back to studying music theory.

Comment: Have you contacted your ISP about the problem?  It looks like they're blocking streaming media or something like that, given that videos on Tumblr don't work either. What about other sites like YouTube or Netflix?  Do those work?

Comment: YouTube works fine. I haven't tried Netflix in a while but my family uses it a lot and I haven't heard any complaints.

Comment: Huzzah! Tumblr works again. Still no luck with Hooktheory

Comment: Have you tried resetting the router to defaults?

Comment: I did. It fixed this issue entirely, but another one popped up. On my main desktop computer, I can no longer go to routerlogin.net or my ip to access the control panel. At first, it just redirected to my IIS hosted website, and then I removed IIS. Now I get the same error as above.

Answer (score 1):

`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` occurs when the connection between the computer and host server is lost. While there are many things could cause this, but mostly will be from the ISP servers. In all cases, you need to call them so they can fix it for you. You cannot fix it since it's not a software settings issue nor a router issue (from what you've tried). It's something related to the ISP servers and they need to fix it, and you might be not the only one affected by this problem, there might be other clients maybe on your area or different areas affected too.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. I was really hoping I wouldn't have to call as Armstrong's customer support is atrocious. Looks like I'm out of luck.

Comment: @JakeRieger I hope they will fix it fast.